# Where can I find AndroidX artifacts list to refer when composing Gradle dependencies?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies, androidx

Where can I find AndroidX artifacts list to refer when composing Gradle dependencies?

In the documentation I can find a reference for packages, but there is no information how are they related to maven artifacts and what versions are out there. This information is needed to put correct dependencies configuration.

Comment: maven.google.com might be useful?

Answer (score 3):

Why down voting? the OP is actually asking very basic yet very important question. These days you have to work on androidx and jet pack libraries and Google have vast documentation for them but the missing piece is a single page for all artifacts with right gradle dependency name and version (latest version).

eg, a list of all like this for simplicity

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0'
```

for OP you can see at

- android developer/jetpack site [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room)
- the [maven repo](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) for now

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of AndroidX packages in relation to the old support libraries:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Here you can keep track of the latest version changes:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn

And in case you also need the architecture components:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes

Answer (score 0):

You can find an exhaustive list of all the Jetpack libraries alongside their most recent releases here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions